# Representing @ symbol in javascript string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access the position of the @ symbol and using the following JS...

```
 <script>

    
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitButton").click(function (e) {

            var at = $('#email').val().lastIndexOf("@");
         
       });
    });

  </script>
```

However this produces a Parse Error:

"");" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

Do I need an escape character here? When I replace the @ with some other character, say a letter.  It does not crash.  This code works...

```
            $("#submitButton").click(function (e) {

            var at = $('#email').val().lastIndexOf("w");
           e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: There must be other code involved.

Comment: You need to post more code, above and below this line

Comment: Just added code above and below

Comment: You've probably missed a `"`, `(`, `}`, etc. somewhere.  The error is not in the line(s) of code you've shown.

Comment: So why does it work with another letter?

Comment: There;s nothing special about the `@` character. You can confirm that by typing `"@"` into your browser console.

Comment: That doesn't look like a JavaScript error. Is it coming when you run the code, or is it a warning from the IDE?

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework that treats `@` as a special marker?

Comment: It does get highlighted in yellow within the string.  That's why I thought it needed an escape.

Comment: Why not try and put together a reproducible example? Everything is just a guess unless you give us more detailed information about the __actual code being executed__

Comment: Ok I put up a reproducible unit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to execute the exact snippet above, the error is telling you that your code is not valid. Specifically, you are missing a closing curly brace (`}`) and a closing parenthesis (`)`)

Here is what it should look like:

```js
$("#submitButton").click(function(e) {

  var at = $('#email').val().lastIndexOf("@");
  console.log('at', at);
  e.preventDefault();
}); // <-- Closing } and )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submitButton">Click Me</button>
<input id="email" type="text" value="something@something.com" />
```

As far as the `@` symbol goes, you do not need to escape it in this scenario.

**EDIT**

The error your getting smells a lot like you're using this in an ASP.NET controller. You might just be including your JS wrong. Try including it by doing it this way:

```
@scripts {
 <script>

    
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitButton").click(function (e) {

            var at = $('#email').val().lastIndexOf("@");
         
       });
    });

  </script>
}
```

Comment: Could it be that I'm not using the right library?  I'm using this...  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"

Comment: No. That is the same library I'm using in my example. Your code is invalid. That is the issue.

Comment: And If I replace it the @ with another character...say a letter.  It's fine.

Comment: You need to add code to prove that. The code you have above doesn't work because it's invalid. Show us the code that works and it will help figure out your problem. My guess is this is a copy/paste issue.

Comment: Are you using this inside an Asp.NET controller?

Comment: No in a cshtml view.

Comment: That produces a red line and a warning that "scripts" does not exist within the current context.  This is not in a controller.  It's in a view

Comment: Useful info...when I surround the @ symbol with letters within the string it's fine.  This only happens when it follows or is followed by a quote

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the @ symbol is also a delineator of commented out code in a view.

Answer (score -1):

I found it!   The @ symbol needs an escape character...another @ symbol. This works...

```
var at = $('#email').val().lastIndexOf("@@");
```

Comment: To be clear, this has **nothing** to do with JavaScript. You're working in some kind of environment that treats `@` as a special character.

Comment: Doesn't razor do that?

Comment: I don't know, but plain JavaScript does *not* do that.

Comment: @John [Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0). This is more of a question of using JS inside a .cshtml file to what razor would parse it as. It's a better idea to have js files separate entirely and load them in. Because if you move this into a normal js file `.lastIndexOf("@@");` will no longer work.